# Salvar dados de formulário no localStorage usando Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Tenho este código de um simples formulário usando o Vue.js, preciso salvar no localStorage. Já tentei de tudo, sempre dá erro, poderiam me sugerir uma idéia para tentar armazenar? Desde já agradeço.

```
<template>

  <form>
   <h3>Cadastro de usuários</h3>

   <div id="app">
  <input type="text"  placeholder="Nome" v-model="name"/>
  </div>

   <div>
  <input type="text"  placeholder="Usuário" v-model="user"/>
  </div>

  <div>
  <input type="password"  placeholder="Senha" v-model="password"/>
  </div>

  <input type="password"  placeholder="Confirmar Senha" v-model="confirmPassword" />

  <div>
  <input type="submit" id="salvar" value="Cadastrar" />
  </div>
   
 </form>

</template>
<script></script>
```

Comment: Onde está o código que "tenta" salvar no localStorage?

Comment: no scritp, tento somente esta opção e já ocorre erro: var vm = new Vue({

(aqui vem suas opções)

})

Comment: const app = new Vue ({ el: 'app', data: { name: '' } }) com este inicio já ocorre erro: 'Vue' is not defined

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta para incluir as informações do comentário. Basta clicar em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/529518/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Acho que um código assim deve funcionar para o seu problema (mesmo não tento muitos detalhes de como você tentou salvar no localStorage)

```
<template>
  <div>
      <form @submit.prevent="submit()">
          <h3>Cadastro de usuários</h3>

          <div id="app">
          <input type="text"  placeholder="Nome" v-model="name"/>
          </div>

          <div>
          <input type="text"  placeholder="Usuário" v-model="user"/>
          </div>

          <div>
          <input type="password"  placeholder="Senha" v-model="password"/>
          </div>

          <input type="password"  placeholder="Confirmar Senha" v-model="confirmPassword" />

          <div>
          <input type="submit" id="salvar" value="Cadastrar" />
          </div>
          
        </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      user: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      const userObject = {
        name: this.name,
        user: this.user,
        password: this.password,
        confirmPassword: this.confirmPassword
      }

      localStorage.setItem("userObject", JSON.stringify(userObject))
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const savedUser = localStorage.getItem("userObject")

    if(savedUser) {
      console.log("usuario do localStorage")
      console.log(JSON.parse(savedUser))
    } 
    else {
      console.log("usuario não existe no localStorage")
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

No método *submit()* eu só pego os dados do form e salvo no localStorage no formato JSON (acredito ser o melhor jeito para salvar essas informalções)

Além disso, implementei o método *mounted()* para mostrar no console quando tem o usuário salvo no localStorage (basta atualizar a página depois de salvar um usuário). Vale lembrar que como eu salvei em JSON eu preciso fazer o parse para poder usar o objeto no código

Answer (score -3):

Para acessar o localStorage utilize:

```
window.localStorage.getItem(blablabla...)
```